# Избавиться от повторений c#

Tags: c#, методы, рефакторинг

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть варианты решения, что бы избавиться от почти одинакового кода.

```
    public void BanPlayer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите порядковый номер игрока, что бы забанить его.");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
        if (players[number]._ban == true)         //players - это список объектов класса Players
            Console.WriteLine("Игрок уже забанен");
        else
        {   
            players[number]._ban = !_ban;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Игрок забанен\n");
        }
    }
    
    public void UnbanPlayer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите порядковый номер игрока, что бы разбанить его.");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
        if (players[number]._ban == false)
            Console.WriteLine("Этот игрок не находится в бане.");
        else
        {
            players[number]._ban = !_ban;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Игрок разбанен\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: минимум первые две строки в каждом методе надо вынести за их пределы и передавать в методы id игрока.... во-вторых проверки не уже забанен или находится в бане имхо не нужны.....ну забанен и что, ну обновите его статус вне зависимости от его текущего статуса....в третьих в качестве результата можно вернуть bool и уже от этого выведите заключительное сообщзение в консоль опять же ВНЕ методов

Comment: Если закрыть глаза на все нарушения и чисто избавляться от дубликатов, то можно примерно [так](https://pastebin.com/8xXu60EJ). Если все же включить здравый смысл, то методы бана должны быть внутри объекта игрока, ибо это его ответственность. То есть у вас должно быть `var result = players[i].Ban();`, а наружу метод отдает либо `bool` (забанен/нет), либо класс результата. Все консольные действия это также должны быть отделены от логики бана.

Comment: Согласен с @EvgeniyZ начиная со слов про здравый смысл. А пример по ссылке плох и не рекомендую.